# How to change a variable

Tags: javascript, variables

How to change a variable once it is set like this:

`const myVar = 'test';`

I have tried the following:

`myVar = 'test2';`

`const myVar = 'test3';`

Comment: Perhaps telling us the language might help, It isn't C or C++ because 'test' isn't a valid char.

Comment: wonder what is the reason for a guy with 750+ rep ask a question like this?

Comment: Consts are pretty universal across languages. It's like trying to find the word for "taxi" in a random human language - it's probably "taxi" or something that sounds very similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Const are constants. They are not intended to be changed once they are set with their initial value.
Simply use a standard variable type without specifying `const`.

```
var myVar = 'test';
myVar = 'another';

const site = 'Stackoverflow';
site = 'Google'; // this will throw an error in Firefox and Chrome (but does not fail in Safari)

const site = 'fb';// trying to redeclare a constant throws an error

console.log(myVar); //outputs another
console.log(site); //Stackoverflow
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Answer (score 1):

You can't. That's the purpose of declaring a variable as `const`. It means it's a constant - it is not going to change.